# How to set back query var author_name after unset it?

Tags: query, pre-get-posts, author-template

I am unsetting the query var `author_name` for querying posts in the author template page. I am using `pre_get_posts` to filter the main query.

After the query is run, I need to set back the `author_name` query var.

This is where I unset it.

```
function wpquery( $query )
     if ( $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query()) {
                $query->set( 'post_status', $post_status );
                unset( $query->query_vars['author_name'] ); 
                $tax_query = array(  
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'tax',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $var
                    )
                );
                $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        }   
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpquery' );
```

After the query runs, i have to set `author_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to use a static variable to store author name, then run again same function on a later hook, maybe 'posts_results' and set back the variable:

```
function wpquery( $query, $query_on_results = NULL ) {
  static $author_name = NULL;
  if ( current_filter() === 'pre_get_posts' ) {
    if ( $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      $query->set( 'post_status', $post_status );
      $author_name =  $query->query_vars['author_name'];
      unset( $query->query_vars['author_name'] ); 
      $tax_query = array(  
        array(
         'taxonomy' => 'tax',
         'field' => 'name',
         'terms' => $var
        )
      );
      $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    } 
  } elseif ( current_filter() === 'posts_results' ) {
    if ( $query_on_results->is_main_query() && ! empty( $author_name ) ) {
      $query_on_results->query_vars['author_name'] = $author_name;
      $author_name = NULL;
      remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 20, 2 );
    }
    // $query represent the 1st arg passed to function, that on posts_result hook
    // is the retrieved posts array. Always return it as is to do not alter results
    return $query;
  }
}   

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpquery' );

add_filter( 'posts_results', 'wpquery', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: I found a problem when unsetting author_name. Author pages with no posts will return a 404 page. Is there a way to fix this?